# Apply Excel SUMIFS formula to R

Tags: r, sumifs

I have df1 and df2, for item selection process using the `sumifs` formula in Excel, I need to convert this formula into R code.

```
> df1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/model/df1.csv")
> df1


YEAR    BAG_1  BAG_2    ITEMS
31-Dec-12   1   1   1230438.453
31-Dec-12   1   2   24327.087
31-Dec-12   1   3   8962.611
31-Dec-12   1   4   3841.119
31-Dec-12   1   5   12803.73
31-Dec-12   2   1   12670.095
31-Dec-12   2   2   342.435
31-Dec-12   2   3   296.777
31-Dec-12   2   4   136.974
31-Dec-12   2   5   9382.719
31-Dec-12   3   1   4493.741
31-Dec-12   3   2   214.718
31-Dec-12   3   3   184.044
31-Dec-12   3   4   92.022
31-Dec-12   3   5   10352.475
31-Dec-12   4   1   1517.586
31-Dec-12   4   2   160.242
31-Dec-12   4   3   122.538
31-Dec-12   4   4   18.852
31-Dec-12   4   5   7606.782
31-Dec-12   5   1   0
31-Dec-12   5   2   0
31-Dec-12   5   3   0
31-Dec-12   5   4   0
31-Dec-12   5   5   17084
31-Dec-13   1   2   16215.914
31-Dec-13   1   3   8731.646
31-Dec-13   1   4   7484.268
31-Dec-13   1   5   42410.852
31-Dec-13   2   1   15279.943
31-Dec-13   2   2   442.096
31-Dec-13   2   3   303.941
31-Dec-13   2   4   138.155
31-Dec-13   2   5   11466.865
31-Dec-13   3   1   4801.223
31-Dec-13   3   2   217.477
31-Dec-13   3   3   150.561
31-Dec-13   3   4   16.729
31-Dec-13   3   5   11543.01
31-Dec-13   4   1   2289.504
31-Dec-13   4   2   177.164
31-Dec-13   4   3   149.908
31-Dec-13   4   4   40.884
31-Dec-13   4   5   10970.54
31-Dec-13   5   1   0
31-Dec-13   5   2   0
31-Dec-13   5   3   0
31-Dec-13   5   4   0
31-Dec-13   5   5   21952
31-Dec-14   1   1   1160393.766
31-Dec-14   1   2   15829.086
31-Dec-14   1   3   8523.354
31-Dec-14   1   4   4870.488
31-Dec-14   1   5   28005.306
31-Dec-14   2   1   15095.349
31-Dec-14   2   2   461.808
31-Dec-14   2   3   202.041
31-Dec-14   2   4   144.315
31-Dec-14   2   5   12959.487
31-Dec-14   3   1   5331.848
31-Dec-14   3   2   324.234
31-Dec-14   3   3   162.117
31-Dec-14   3   4   108.078
31-Dec-14   3   5   12086.723
31-Dec-14   4   1   1810.35
31-Dec-14   4   2   174.33
31-Dec-14   4   3   120.69
31-Dec-14   4   4   13.41
31-Dec-14   4   5   11291.22
31-Dec-14   5   1   0
31-Dec-14   5   2   0
31-Dec-14   5   3   0
31-Dec-14   5   4   0
31-Dec-14   5   5   24210
31-Dec-15   1   1   1195886.146
31-Dec-15   1   2   17642.156
31-Dec-15   1   3   10081.232
31-Dec-15   1   4   6300.77
31-Dec-15   1   5   30243.696
31-Dec-15   2   1   15146.97
31-Dec-15   2   2   419.916
31-Dec-15   2   3   209.958
31-Dec-15   2   4   59.988
31-Dec-15   2   5   14157.168
31-Dec-15   3   1   4893.72
31-Dec-15   3   2   266.645
31-Dec-15   3   3   172.535
31-Dec-15   3   4   31.37
31-Dec-15   3   5   10320.73
31-Dec-15   4   1   1722.034
31-Dec-15   4   2   169.778
31-Dec-15   4   3   109.143
31-Dec-15   4   4   72.762
31-Dec-15   4   5   10053.283
31-Dec-15   5   1   0
31-Dec-15   5   2   0
31-Dec-15   5   3   0
31-Dec-15   5   4   0
31-Dec-15   5   5   23566
31-Dec-16   1   1   1160252.431
31-Dec-16   1   2   27241.786
31-Dec-16   1   3   16097.419
31-Dec-16   1   4   12382.63
31-Dec-16   1   5   23526.997
31-Dec-16   2   1   16477.812
31-Dec-16   2   2   2917.278
31-Dec-16   2   3   1442.61
31-Dec-16   2   4   1250.262
31-Dec-16   2   5   10002.096
31-Dec-16   3   1   5474.862
31-Dec-16   3   2   815.028
31-Dec-16   3   3   921.336
31-Dec-16   3   4   637.848
31-Dec-16   3   5   9851.208
31-Dec-16   4   1   2300.886
31-Dec-16   4   2   383.481
31-Dec-16   4   3   326.669
31-Dec-16   4   4   426.09
31-Dec-16   4   5   10765.874
31-Dec-16   5   1   0
31-Dec-16   5   2   0
31-Dec-16   5   3   0
31-Dec-16   5   4   0
31-Dec-16   5   5   30662
```

dataframe 2 - df2

```
> df2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/model/df2.csv")
> df2

CurrentYEAR     BAG_1   BAG_2

16-Dec      1   1
16-Dec      1   2
16-Dec      1   3
16-Dec      1   4
16-Dec      1   5
16-Dec      2   1
16-Dec      2   2
16-Dec      2   3
16-Dec      2   4
16-Dec      2   5
16-Dec      3   1
16-Dec      3   2
16-Dec      3   3
16-Dec      3   4
16-Dec      3   5
16-Dec      4   1
16-Dec      4   2
16-Dec      4   3
16-Dec      4   4
16-Dec      4   5
16-Dec      5   1
16-Dec      5   2
16-Dec      5   3
16-Dec      5   4
16-Dec      5   5
```

I have a formula:

```
IN EXCEL - FOR DF1 - 
COLUMN A - SR.NO 
COLUMN B - YEAR
```

Pleaes ignore column A and B, formula starts with column C:

```
BAG_1 - COLUMN IN EXCEL - C
BAG_2 - D
ITEMS - E
```

IN EXCEL - FOR DF2 -

```
BAG_1 - COLUMN IN EXCEL - I
BAG_2 - J
SELECTED_ITEMS - K
REJECTED_ITEMS - L
```

under SELECTED_ITEMS, for cell 1 - below SELECTED_ITEMS column - apply the below formula:

```
=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$126,C2:$C$126,I2,$D$2:$D$126,J2)
```

unders REJECTED_ITEMS, for cell 1 - below REJECTED_ITEMS column - apply the below formula:

```
=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$126,$C$2:$C$126,I2)
```

Expected output:

```
c_YEAR  BAG_1    BAG_2     SELECTED_ITEMS   REJECTED_ITEMS
16-Dec  1       1           5919506.116     6245028.263
16-Dec  1       2           101256.029      6245028.263
16-Dec  1       3           52396.262       6245028.263
16-Dec  1       4           34879.275       6245028.263
16-Dec  1       5           136990.581      6245028.263
16-Dec  2       1           74670.169       141407.058
16-Dec  2       2           4583.533        141407.058
16-Dec  2       3           2455.327        141407.058
16-Dec  2       4           1729.694        141407.058
16-Dec  2       5           57968.335       141407.058
16-Dec  3       1           24995.394       83464.282
16-Dec  3       2           1838.102        83464.282
16-Dec  3       3           1590.593        83464.282
16-Dec  3       4           886.047         83464.282
16-Dec  3       5           54154.146       83464.282
16-Dec  4       1           9640.36         62794
16-Dec  4       2           1064.995        62794
16-Dec  4       3           828.948         62794
16-Dec  4       4           571.998         62794
16-Dec  4       5           50687.699       62794
16-Dec  5       1           0               117474
16-Dec  5       2           0               117474
16-Dec  5       3           0               117474
16-Dec  5       4           0               117474
16-Dec  5       5           117474          117474
```

please help me to write this formula into r code as per the expected output.

structures:

```
dput(df1)

structure(list(YEAR = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("31-Dec-12", 
"31-Dec-13", "31-Dec-14", "31-Dec-15", "31-Dec-16"), class = "factor"), 
    BAG_1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L), BAG_1.1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), ITEMS = c(1230438.453, 24327.087, 
    8962.611, 3841.119, 12803.73, 12670.095, 342.435, 296.777, 
    136.974, 9382.719, 4493.741, 214.718, 184.044, 92.022, 10352.475, 
    1517.586, 160.242, 122.538, 18.852, 7606.782, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    17084, 1172535.32, 16215.914, 8731.646, 7484.268, 42410.852, 
    15279.943, 442.096, 303.941, 138.155, 11466.865, 4801.223, 
    217.477, 150.561, 16.729, 11543.01, 2289.504, 177.164, 149.908, 
    40.884, 10970.54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21952, 1160393.766, 15829.086, 
    8523.354, 4870.488, 28005.306, 15095.349, 461.808, 202.041, 
    144.315, 12959.487, 5331.848, 324.234, 162.117, 108.078, 
    12086.723, 1810.35, 174.33, 120.69, 13.41, 11291.22, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 24210, 1195886.146, 17642.156, 10081.232, 6300.77, 
    30243.696, 15146.97, 419.916, 209.958, 59.988, 14157.168, 
    4893.72, 266.645, 172.535, 31.37, 10320.73, 1722.034, 169.778, 
    109.143, 72.762, 10053.283, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23566, 1160162.06, 
    26814.89979, 15906.05385, 11952.4074, 23427.57938, 16469.63194, 
    2907.825884, 1448.99787, 1243.254659, 9988.289648, 5478.0866, 
    814.7068434, 929.9067234, 635.8147221, 9859.485111, 2305.868381, 
    376.5420847, 323.6473401, 426.5827964, 10770.3594, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 30662, 1867369, 33736, 23, 49, 222, 20995, 8103, 14034, 
    58, 168, 3076, 958, 1584, 10014, 186, 1169, 636, 255, 869, 
    8022, 1252, 467, 119, 219, 451798)), .Names = c("YEAR", "BAG_1", 
"BAG_1.1", "ITEMS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-150L))


    dput(df2)

structure(list(Current.YEAR = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Dec-16", class = "factor"), BAG_1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), BAG_2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("Current.YEAR", "BAG_1", "BAG_2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Comment: form dataframes 1 and 2 above, how did you get `5919506.116  and 6245028.263
`

Comment: Can you also explain in plain English the algorithm? Providing data in an easy-to-paste manner may elicit more responses.

Comment: 5919506.116 = =SUMIFS($E$2:$E$126,C2:$C$126,I2,$D$2:$D$126,J2) ,     6245028.263 =SUMIFS($E$2:$E$126,$C$2:$C$126,I2)

Comment: @roman - how can i give you the structure of all the data frames?

Comment: Fairly easy. Try `dput(head(x), 10)`. There are more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: is this fine now?

Comment: Please check your shift key. It seems to get stuck occasionally.

Comment: Also, please describe the task in plain English without referring to Excel. I have only a vague idea what Excel's `sumif` does but could probably answer the R question easily.

Comment: @Roland `sumif` is something like filter on column1, and sum column2. And `sumifs` is filter on column1,2,x, and sum on columnY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have what you want:

```
# read in your data and convert to data.table
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(...) # all that stuff you have above
names(df1) <- tolower(names(df1))
dt1 <- data.table(df1)

# calculate column K of your Excel
result_1 <- dt1[ , .(selected_items = sum(items)), by=.(bag_1, bag_2)]

# calculate column L of your Excel
result_2 <- dt1[ , .(rejected_items = sum(items)), by=.(bag_1)]

# put results next to each other to match your example
result <- merge(result_1, result_2, by="bag_1", all=TRUE)
```

Comment: you are the GEM. it worked. thank you. :)

Comment: there's an issue with the result2 - rejected item, values does not match as per the expected out.

Comment: Hey Robby - I've edited my proposed solution. I think it will now give you what you're looking for.